# Trim and btrfs with raid1

Tags: btrfs, ssd, raid1, trim

I know that btrfs support trim/discard, as a mount option or manually (`fstrim -A`).

I want to made a raid1 of ssd, I will get any problem with trim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems all ok on btrfs raid1 on Slackware 15

```
 fstrim -Av
    /boot: 912,8 MiB (957186048 bytes) trimmed on /dev/md0
    /: 1,8 TiB (1932357992448 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mapper/luksROOTENC2
```